# How to give names to ssh buffers in emacs

Tags: emacs, ssh, buffer, title

When open an ssh shell through emacs, may keybindings are disabled so I can still use the remote shell bindings. Though, names like ssh, ssh<1>, ssh<2> are not very informative, and thus I'd like to change the title of these buffers.

How am I suposed to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just discovered that the ssh buffer is in *term mode*. I middle clicked the *term* word in the status bar and there was help being displayed. By reading the help I discovered that in order to let the keypresses be intercepted by emacs instead of being directly sent to the terminal I would have to press `C-x` first. So I just executed `C-x M-x rename-buffer` and it worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

Use `rename-buffer`.

If you run ssh in (e)shell- or term-mode there are no hooks to do this automatically but you could advise the respective commands bound to <kbd>RET</kbd>.

Comment: But, How can I invoke rename-buffer in the ssh buffer if I cannot execute M-x?!?!

Comment: I searched a bit, but I found no package that generates buffers named this. So what package are you using?

Comment: well... I am using emacs-starter kit, so it may be something from it. Anyway, I suspect that you will get the behaviour I have mentioned when you type ssh <user>@<host> in a eshell buffer.

Comment: I looked into the starterkit and found nothing that could cause this. vanilla eshell doesn't change the buffer name, it stays `*eshell*`. Could you add the exact workflow how you get an `ssh` buffer?

Comment: (The question is already answered) though, the workflow is: `M-x eshell ssh <user>@host` . M-x does nothing then.